# Creating Timeline In Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview

I'm trying to make a nice application and in this application;
I want to make a timeline and timeline will include `"Image", "2 TextBlock" and "2 Buttons"`.
How can I create something like that. I will get the my data from `web api service`.
I found to make async calls to get data but could not created the schema of the timeline.

**How can I do something like that ?**

[image]

Waiting your advices, thank you. I googled so much but found basic `listviews` all the time.

Comment: You can create XML file similar to your image. use Relative and Linear Layouts to design you structure

Comment: I use fragment view for my tabs. How can I put that inside of fragmentlayout ?

Comment: you can design a xml and can inflate it to your fragment layout through code.

Comment: Can you help me about that button issue ? How can I divide the linear layout equal 2 pieces ? thanks.

Comment: you can assign weightsum =1 to layout and layout-weight=0.5 to its both child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <LinearLayout orientation="vertical">

</ImageView>

<LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
</TextBox>
</TextBox>
</LinearLauout>

<LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
</Button>
</Button>
</LinearLauout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following image describes the design view of your page

[image: THIS FULFILLS YOUR REQUIREMENT]

**EDIT:** How can I divide the linear layout equal 2 pieces ?

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="5"
       />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="5" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you help me about that button issue ? How can I divide the linear layout equal 2 pieces ? thanks.

Comment: @KuthayGumus I have updated the answer plz have a look